# Convert data from long format to wide format

Tags: javascript, pivot, data-forge

I am trying to use Data-Forge to pivot a dataframe as per below. I have been through all the examples I could find using the pivot function, but it doesn't seem to do this type of long to wide format pivot. Is there any way to do this is Data-Forge?

```
const df = new dataForge.DataFrame([
  { cat: "A", group: "red", val: 1 },
  { cat: "A", group: "blue", val: 2 },
  { cat: "B", group: "red", val: 3 },
  { cat: "B", group: "blue", val: 4 },
  { cat: "C", group: "red", val: 5 },
  { cat: "C", group: "blue", val: 6 },
]);
const expected = [
  { group: "red", A: 1, B: 3, C: 5 },
  { group: "blue", A: 2, B: 4, C: 6 },
];
```

Comment: You should post also what you have tried and where you have an error if any

Comment: I have tried using the pivot function. There is no error but it doesn't produce the expected output, all the examples don't do long to wide pivoting.